# A strong form of Mostow rigidity without geometrization?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Mostow rigidity theorem says that two closed hyperbolic manifolds with isomorphic fundamental groups are isometric.

Here is my question: suppose that $M$ and $N$ are two closed 3-manifolds such that $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent and such that $N$ is hyperbolic. Is it possible to prove that $M$ and $N$ are homeomorphic (diffeomorphic) without using geometrization theorem?

Answer (score 10):

Gabai proved that homotopy hyperbolic 3-manifolds are *virtually* hyperbolic, in the paper of that name:

> Gabai, David, Homotopy hyperbolic 3-manifolds are virtually
> hyperbolic.
> *J. Amer. Math. Soc.* 7 (1994), no. 1, 193–198.

I suspect this is the best you can do without geometrisation.

Comment: There is anoher paper "Homotopy Hyperbolic 3-Manifolds Are Hyperbolic" by Gabai, Meyerhoff, and N. Thurston, https://www.jstor.org/stable/3597207?seq=1 saying that a homotopy equivalence from a hyperbolic 3-manifold to a closed irreducible 3-manifold is homotopic to a diffeomorphism. Getting rid of  "irreducability" assumption is impossible without Poincare conjecture (just take the connected sum of a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold with a homotopy sphere).

Comment: PS Virtually hyperbolic = has a finite cover admitting a hyperbolic structure